# implicit cast from enum to another type (CloudBlobContainer)

Tags: c#, enums, azure-storage, implicit-conversion

Is it possible to cast an enum to another object?

I have enumarated a list of blob containers. I'd like to implicitly cast the enum type into the named `CloudBlobContainer`

Here is an example of what i've tried

```
public static class BlobContainerCasts
{
    public static implicit operator CloudBlobContainer(EnumTypes.BlobContainerNames BlobContainerName)
    {
        return CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(Enum.GetName(typeof(EnumTypes.BlobContainerNames), BlobContainerName));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it won't compile because it doesn't respect the rule about User-defined conversion (it must convert to or from the enclosing type)

So, is there a way to do it without creating a method like this one?

```
public CloudBlobContainer GetBlobContainer(EnumTypes.BlobContainerNames BlobContainerName)
{...}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I take it, you can't extend `CloudBlobContainer`?

Comment: Would it be possible to just making a constructor for `CloudBlobContainer` that takes in the enum value? Seems like a more intuitive design than having implicit casting from an enum to a class. If the logic to transition from the enum to the class is more complicated, a normal "factory" pattern would be well suited to that too.

Comment: Endeed, the cast may look wired. `CloudBlobContainer` is part of the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll`, I didn't know any way to add constructor to it without extend `CloudBlobContainer`. I will use an extension method. I think it is the best way in my context. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on breischl answere, here is the solution:

```
public static CloudBlobContainerExtensions {
    public static CloudBlobContainer GetContainer(this EnumTypes.BlobContainerNames BlobContainerName)
    {
        return CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(Enum.GetName(typeof(EnumTypes.BlobContainerNames), BlobContainerName));
    }
}

//elsewhere
var myContainer = EnumTypes.BlobContainerNames.somename.GetContainer();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extension method:

```
public static CloudBlobContainerExtensions {
    public static CloudBlobContainer GetContainer(this EnumTypes.BlobContainerNames BlobContainerName)
    {
        return CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(Enum.GetName(typeof(EnumTypes.BlobContainerNames), BlobContainerName));
    }
}
//elsewhere
var myContainer = CloudBlobContainer.GetContainer(EnumTypes.BlobContainerNames.SomeName);
```

Side note: are you sure you want to explicitly reference the DevelopmentStorageAccount instead of fetching the storage account from a setting?

Comment: This code is only used for development. I will use settings later. I realy believed there was a way to use a cast. Anyway, thank you for your answere!

Comment: However, the `//elswere` part of your code isn't right. It's more something like `EnumTypes.BlobContainerNames.somename.GetContainer()` Since I am using the name of the enum to name my container, I have to respect the `CloudBlobContainer` naming rules (lowercase).